# ASP.NET Core DI error: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate - Optional controller constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am receiving this error when trying to activate an injected service into my API controller:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MyApp.Interfaces.IFooService' while attempting to activate 'MyApp.Controllers.FooController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I know why I'm getting this error.  I've got this logic where my service collection is built, which won't add the service if IsDisabled is true:

```
var fooServiceConfiguration = FooServiceConfigurationHelper<IFooService>.GetFooServiceConfiguration(Configuration);
            if (!fooServiceConfiguration.IsDisabled)
                services.AddTransient(s => ServiceHelper.GetService<IFooService>(fooServiceConfiguration));
```

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is NOT add the service to the collection IF we've configured it to be disabled.  The reason for this is to avoid constructing the service and its dependencies if we've "turned it off" in configuration settings (bool IsDisabled).

But the controller obviously doesn't know that the service wasn't created, resulting in this error.

```
public MyApiController(ILogger<MyApiController> logger, IFooService fooService, IBarService barService)
```

I'm trying to find out if there's a best practice for this situation, whether its overloaded controller constructors, or something else.  I'll be happy to offer more detail if needed.

Comment: Use the [Null Object design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). Instead *not* registering it, register an empty implementation (the so called "Null Object").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Essentially, what I'm trying to do is NOT add the service to the
>   collection IF we've configured it to be disabled. The reason for this
>   is to avoid constructing the service and its dependencies if we've
>   "turned it off" in configuration settings (bool IsDisabled).

This is IOC. You 'shouldnt' do that. Its either a dependency for that class or it isnt. You can hack it, but it becomes an ugly anti-pattern that requires handling the null. That adds logic to the class, and makes unit testing a bit more tricky. This post talks about it in more detail: https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2013/di-anti-pattern-multiple-constructors/#Dependencies-should-hardly-ever-be-optional

Comment: That make sense. I think I just need to figure out how to make the construction of those injected services less costly so that this if/then logic in the service configuration wouldn't even need to be considered. Thanks for the article link.